# Matrices in OpenGL

Tags: math, opengl, 3d

So I am learning OpenGL with as the main resource having the "Red book". I am reading about matrix algebra, rotation/scaling/transform matrices and everything is great, but I just don't get one simple thing. Let's say the function glLoadIdentity(). It sets the default matrix of 4x4. So it sets 3 vertices and 1 point: (1,0,0) (0,1,0) (0,0,1) vertices, (0,0,0) point. But my question is, what do those correspond? Generally speaking, what does a matrix correspond in OpenGL? I got an idea that these are the directions of axies. But the axies of what? The camera?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenGL matrices only correspond to a transformation, moving objects, vectors and points defined in one coordinate space to another. If you have a matrix M (m11 - m44 as shown below) and a vector V (v1 - v4) in one coordinate space then multiplying by M will convert your V vector (which could describe a movement vector, object location or an object vertex) to W (w1-w4) in a different coordinate space:

```
| m11 m12 m13 m14 |   | v1 |     | w1 |
| m21 m22 m23 m24 |   | v2 |     | w2 |
| m31 m32 m33 m34 | X | v3 |  =  | w3 |
| m41 m42 m43 m44 |   | v4 |     | w4 |
```

Where:

```
w1 = m11 * v1 + m12 * v2 + m13 * v3 + m14 * v4
w2 = m21 * v1 + m22 * v2 + m23 * v3 + m24 * v4
w3 = m31 * v1 + m32 * v2 + m33 * v3 + m34 * v4
w4 = m41 * v1 + m42 * v2 + m43 * v3 + m44 * v4
```

So if we think of v1 - v3 as the old x, y and z coordinates and set v4 to 1, then we can think of w1 - w3 as the new x, y and z coordinates there are a few things we can see:
  m11 is a multiplier from the old x coordinate to the new one so it's used in scale transformations (and similarly for m22 and m33)
  m14 multiplied by 1 and added to the new x coordinate so it is used for translations (and similarly for m24 and m34)

Rotations are a little harder to conceptualise but they are done by setting the other matrix values to appropriate values. You can read more here: http://gpwiki.org/index.php/Matrix_math

Comment: Oh, so by calling glLoadIdentity() we just reset the matrix to the one (identity matrix), which multiplicity with the vector will result the same vector? In other words, will not affect the object in any way? We do that since the draw function draws the objects using the currently loaded matrix? Do I understand it right?

Answer (score 0):

The default matrix is simply the identity matrix:

```
/1 0 0 0\
|0 1 0 0|
|0 0 1 0|
\0 0 0 1/
```

In the more general case (ignoring perspective and possibly other exotic transforms)...

```
/a d g j\
|b e h k|
|c f i l|
\0 0 0 1/
```

...the components of the transformed coordinate system are as follows:

```
         /a\
X-axis = |b|
         \c/

         /d\
Y-axis = |e|
         \f/


         /g\
Z-axis = |h|
         \i/

         /j\
Origin = |k|
         \l/
```

If you correlate these to the identity matrix, you can see where your "3 vertices and 1 point" come from.

Beyond the identity matrix, this applies to any transform — rotation, translation, etc. — that keeps the bottom row at (0 0 0 1), and provides a simple way to visualise such transforms. Simply think of the four components above as representing where the axes (1 0 0), (0 1 0), (0 0 1) and the origin (0 0 0) end up after being transformed by the matrix (keeping in mind that the axes are not absolute, but relative to the origin).